# How do I use ":nth-of-type" to select an element after the element is updated by jQuery?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to style the first element with a class that I've added through jQuery.

Unfortunately, my CSS styling is ignored when I use the `:nth-of-type(1)` selector.

[**Here is the Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xdL8sdmf/1/)

When you click the button "World", the first word should be red but it isn't.

How do I use `:nth-of-type` to select an element after a jQuery updates the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery, fall back to it when CSS fails you. This doesn't mean inline styles, let's continue to use classes (modified [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xdL8sdmf/7/)):

Your new CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.seen {
    display: inline-block;
}

.first {
    color: red;
}
```

The new class `.first` replaces your attempt to match via CSS. We'll apply it with jQuery:

```
$( "button.1" ).click(function () {
    $("span.1").toggleClass("seen hidden");
    $("span").removeClass("first");
    $(".seen:first").addClass("first");
});

$( "button.2" ).click(function () {
    $("span.2").toggleClass("seen hidden");
    $("span").removeClass("first");
    $(".seen:first").addClass("first");
});
```

Now that things are working we've gotten to the point of "passing our test" (even though no test is written here, this is the point we'd be at). The next step is refactor. We've got some repetitive bits. Let's clean it up. Naively I may try and do this:

```
var selectFirst = function() {
    $("span").removeClass("first");
    $(".seen:first").addClass("first");
};

$( "button.1" ).click(function () {
    $("span.1").toggleClass("seen hidden");
    selectFirst();
});

$( "button.2" ).click(function () {
    $("span.2").toggleClass("seen hidden");
    selectFirst();
});
```

But in reality we can do much better by moving around some information in the HTML and changing our jQuery slightly (working [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xdL8sdmf/11/)):

Our new HTML looks like this:

```
<span class="hidden" data-number="1">Hello</span>
<span class="hidden" data-number="2">World</span>
<span class="hidden" data-number="1">Hello</span>
<span class="hidden" data-number="2">World</span>

<button data-target-number="1">Hello</button>
<button data-target-number="2">World</button>
```

Notice the usage of `data-` attributes. Much cleaner, the `1` and `2` as classes was really bogging down that attribute with useless information.

Let's see what effect that had on the jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var number = $(this).data("target-number"),
        // This line could also be "span[data-number=" + number + "]"
        targetSelector = ["span[data-number=", number, "]"].join("");

    $(targetSelector).toggleClass("seen hidden");
    $(".first").removeClass("first");
    $(".seen:first").addClass("first");
});
```

That's it, only one function! No repeating ourself. The refactor was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.hidden:first-child + .seen, .seen:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dcvgmy7c/1/)**

Updated to solve the issue represented in below comment:

```
.hidden:first-child ~ .seen, .seen:first-child {
    color: red;
}
.hidden:first-child ~ span.seen ~ span.seen {
    color: black;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dcvgmy7c/3/)**

Comment: This is fickle and breaks easily when things are changed, like in this [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dcvgmy7c/2/) introducing a new hidden element. This won't happen if you use a more generalized solution similar to mine, [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xdL8sdmf/12/)

Comment: @BrandonBuck though the OP hasn't mentioned that case, I solved it for you. [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dcvgmy7c/3/).

Comment: I was pointing out how easy it is to break something depending so heavily on the current markup which inevitably changes at some point. Props on fixing it, I recommend improving your answer with it.